# How do I get better terminal output from Jasmine-node?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node, frisby.js

I'm using `jasmine-node` with `frisby` when I run my tests all I get in the terminal output is red and green dots, I want to see a checklist of all the specs and whether they passed or failed similar to Mocha and Chai.

Any ideas on how to get this desired output from Jasmine?

Comment: Similar question: how to run jasmine through node with `npm test`. Flag `--verbose` does not work there as expected ... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Use `--verbose` argument for `jasmine-node` as follows:

```
jasmine-node --verbose yourSpec.js
```

There are other arguments that you might find helpful. See [documentation here.](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node#usage)